# How To Reduce This Function In MS Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I'm looking to reduce this function In MS Excel 2013 !
my function is :

`=IF(OR(AND(B5>E3;F3=0);AND(B5>E4;F4=0);AND(B5>E5;F5=0);AND(B5>E6;F6=0);AND(B5>E7;F7=0);AND(B5>E8;F8=0);AND(B5>E9;F9=0);AND(B5>E10;F10=0));"true";"false")`

My function is currently working with success :D!

But, I hope to reduce (shorten) it because I want to repeat this format in many other places in the same Excel File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(E:E,"<"&B5,F:F,0)>0,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

In your format:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(E:E;"<"&B5;F:F;0)>0;"TRUE";"FALSE")
```

[image]

Comment: Since you are using the OR in your IF statement we can look for any combination where column F is 0 and Column E is less then B5.  The countifs counts where those conditions are true.  If any are present it will be greater than 0 and thus true. @dr.Vbs

Comment: @pnuts Maybe the OP is in a different language and actually wants the English words and not the local translation?  I got yelled at one time for assuming.

Comment: +1 Nice! I'm learning these array formulas more and more (of which you are undoubtedly skilled at). Almost had it. :-)

Comment: or just `=TEXT(COUNTIFS(E:E,"<"&B5,F:F,0)>0,)`. Maybe even `=TEXT((E:E<B7)*(F:F=0)>0,)`

Comment: @Slai see my comment to pnut above.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter version, but you have to enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=IF((B5>E3:E10)*(F3:F10=0);"true";"false")
```

or

```
=IF((B5>E:E)*(F:F=0);"true";"false")
```

maybe even

```
=IF((B5<=E:E)+F:F;"false";"true")
```